# MySQL Query gives error: unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know this error is usually a problem with unclosed quotes and such, but I can't seem to find the problem here. I suspect it's something to do with the parentheses, who knows though.

The error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
```

The query:

```
$result = @mysql_query('select * from quotes inner join game on game.id=quotes.game_id inner join person on person.id=quotes.speaker_id where game.id = ' . $gameid . ' and person.id in (SELECT person.id
    FROM person
    JOIN coach ON person.id = coach.person_id
    JOIN team  ON coach.team_id = team.id where team.id=' . $name '

    Union

    SELECT person.id
    FROM person
    JOIN player ON person.id = player.person_id
    JOIN team  ON player.team_id = team.id where team.id=' . $name . ')');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You write:

```
' ... JOIN team  ON coach.team_id = team.id where team.id=' . $name ' ...
```

Where it should be:

```
' ... JOIN team  ON coach.team_id = team.id where team.id=' . $name . ' ...
```

(note the dot right behind $name)

Comment: Thank you, sometimes all it takes is a fresh pair of eyes to find an error that stupid. I'll accept this answer when it allows me to.